# Differences For i!=array.length vs i<array.length

Tags: java

This two for loops shows same result, I see the first for loop more than to the second one. What are the performance and readability differences between them.

```
    int arr[] = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6}; 
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i!=arr.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
```

Comment: Performance is the same, but if you set `i = 6` in the second one, it turns into an endless loop

Comment: Related (possibly even a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040684/loop-condition-why-not-equal-instead-of-lower-than

Comment: I think performances are the same as it's just comparison operation. However, the second one is more general. If, for a reason, in a more complex code, `i` become greater that `arr.length`, the loop will continue while the first one will stop.

Comment: A good practice is to think your code to be the more robust possible. You don't know if someone will change something, etc... So prevent any error cause. Using `!=` means you are sure at some point you will reach the specific value. `<` stops wether you reach your expected value or you go over.

Comment: Unless you are doing some reaaaaally extreme number crunching (AI, graphics, etc) then you don't have to care much about such micro-optimizations. And you even don't need to care about this case at all. `< arr.length` is the standard way to do it, people love standards. Not to mention what could happen if `i` skips `arr.length`inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I'd say readability is in the eye of the beholder, so that part would be off-topic for SO.

There won't be a performance difference that will matter. (And as always: Worry about a performance problem when you have a performance problem to worry about. :-) )

One pragmatic reason for using `<` rather than `!=` is that if you're in the habit of writing `!=` and then need to write a loop that increases `i` by more than one at some point, you might be more likely to accidentally write code causing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
int arr[] = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6}; 
for (int i = 0; i != arr.length; i += 2) {
    System.out.print(arr[i]); // Causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when it tries to access arr[6]
}
```

(Or if you're not diong array access or similar [you aren't in your question's code, for instance], an endless loop.)